# JQ transform a number upto 2 precision

Tags: json, jq, transform

I am using this library for JQ transformation.

https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq/tree/master/0.x

How can we transform a number upto 2 precision?
Is there any inbuilt function in jq for this?
Currently, It is supporting 1 precision
.

Requirement:
for ex:
1 to 1.00,
1.0 to 1.00,
1.00 to 1.00,
1.1 to 1.10. etc

Comment: In jq, numbers only consist of their values. They don't store any respresentational information such as trailing zeros. Of course, you can convert numbers into strings, i.e. a concatenation of characters where having trailing characters representing zeros is perfectly valid. Yet, a string wouldn't store the original numeric value anymore, but you may be able to convert such a string back again into a number. That said, show us what you did to accomplish that 1-digit precision (1 to 1.0, 1.1 to 1.1, 1.25 to 1.2 or 1.3 (?) etc.), and we can help you adapt that method to get a 2-digit precision.

Comment: I got your point.We have to convert the number into string then process it.The library which i am using currently, It is supporting 1 precision by default.